# Serving django app in an intended location (NGINX)

Tags: python, django, web, nginx, webserver

I have a web server serving my Django app (using NGINX) and I need to access it in a defined "location".

For example, I access my Django app XPTO in "ip:port/" but I need to access it like "ip:port/XPTO/". All urls specified in Django have to be resolved "after" this "base url".

Anyway I can do this without messing with my "urls.py" in Django? I had tried some configurations on NGINX but nothing worked.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `location` directive in your nginx config.

You probably have something right now that looks like this:

```
location / {
    ...
}
```

To serve under XPTO instead you want this:

```
location /XPTO/ {
    ...
}
```

You also need to be sure that you generate all internal links via the `url` tag or the `reverse` function, so that they will automatically include the prefix.

If this doesn't work, please show us your current nginx config (edit it into the question) and we may be able to provide more specific advice.

Comment: I had tried that before also and it seems to be the way but it does not "fully" work as expected. It works at the NGINX level (i.e. NGINX accepts the correct URLS and denies the others) but then Django removes the /XPTO/ in the url and then NGINX does not know the next location. I want Django to assume it always as the base URL so that the /XPTO/ is always on the URL. 

If I was too confusing, what happens is:
/xpto/users -> NGINX,
/users/ -> Django,
/users/2/ -> NGINX, 
NGINX does not know that location.

Comment: Django does not remove /XPTO/ from url.
When you ask NGINX for /XPTO/ uri it will return 302 status code and redirect to your UWSGI root url, which is your django root url

Comment: You need to be sure that you generate all internal links via the `url` tag or the `reverse` function, so that they will automatically include the prefix.

Comment: @DanielRoseman great, thanks, I've added that information to the answer.